# Normal Curvature and Differential Map

Tags: differential-geometry, curvature

I was doing an exercise in which I am supposed to conclude that because all of the normal curvatures at a given point $p$ are zero, $dN_p=0$. This is supposed to be trivial but I do not really understand why.

The idea of the exercise:

We are considering the rotation if the curve $z=y^4$ about the $z$ axis.

The goal is to show that, at $p=(0,0,0)$, $dN_p=0$.

To see this, we observed that the curvature of our curve at $p$ is zero.

Since the $xy$ plane is a tangent plane to the surface at $p$, the normal vector $N(p)$ is parallel to the $z$ axis.

Therefore, any normal section has curvature zero, since they are all obtained through rotations of our curve.

Now, because all normal curvatures are zero at $p$, we can conclude $dN_p=0$.

And this is the conlcusion I do not understand.

Thank you

Exercise in Manfredo do Carmo's book.

Comment: What are principal curvatures?

Comment: Those will only appear in the next section of the book. This example is supposed to just use the definition of normal section, curvature and normal curvature..

Comment: It's very hard for us to guess what you know and what you do not know. So how is normal curvature related to $dN_p$?

Comment: @TedShifrin I just edited the post. Hope this helps you, so you can help me :)

Comment: @TedShifrin Sir, you've clearly shown that you know the answer. I am stuck and I really want to understand this. Could you please answer my question? Thank you. Maybe the hints are good but I'm new at this, I've been trying hard and cannot reach any conclusions.

Comment: I added the solution for you. You might find my differential geometry text (linked in my profile) a bit more explicit than DoCarmo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HINT**: Compute $dN_p(v)$ by the definition. What is the surface normal along the normal slice of the surface in direction $v$? (Use the fact that this is a surface of revolution.)

**EDIT**: As I suggested both in the hint and in a further comment, you compute $dN_p(v)=(N\circ\alpha)'(0)$ where $\alpha(t)$ is a curve in the surface $S$ with $\alpha(0)=p$ and $\alpha'(0)=v\in T_pS$. Take $v$ to be a unit vector. The obvious curve $\alpha$ to take is the slice of $S$ by the vertical plane containing $v$. Along $\alpha$, we have $N=\pm n$, where $n$ is the principal normal of the *plane* curve $\alpha$. Now, $dN_p(v) = (N\circ\alpha)'(0) = \pm n'(0) = \mp k(0)t(0) = 0$.

Comment: This is my recent attempt: At the origin, the surface's normal is always the same, along whatever direction, since this is a surface of revolution. Now, we know all normal curvatures are zero at the origin. So, it follows that the second fundamental form is always zero at given velocity vectors . And since the second fundamental form is $-<dN_P(v),v>$ and $v$ is never the null vector, yields $dN_p(v)$ is always zero. Is this correct?

Comment: No, your linear algebra is flawed. Try the matrix $A=\left[\begin{matrix} 0&1\\-1&0\end{matrix}\right]$. Instead, follow the detailed hint I gave you (for a good reason).

Comment: $\alpha (t)= x(u(t),v(t))$. Computing $dN_p(v)$ by definition: $dN_p(\alpha ')=\frac{\partial x}{\partial u} \frac{\partial u}{\partial t}+\frac{\partial x}{\partial v} \frac{\partial v}{\partial t}$ I don't understand how this is a matrix...the differential is supposed to be a 2x2 matrix, right?

Comment: If you a tangent vector at the origin, what is an obvious curve with that tangent vector? What is $N$ along that curve?

Comment: The $xy$ plane is a tangent plane to the surface at the origin. The normal vector $N(p)$ is parallel to the $z$ axis.